# How can I fix rigify not generating controllers when I deleted and replaced bones with the same name?

Tags: bones, rigify

How can I fix Rigify not generating controllers when I deleted and replaced bones with the same name?

Parenting style is also the same for the bones. I cannot recreate the bones all over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rigify's metarigs, every chain of bones starts with the first bone which has a "Rig type" assigned in pose mode.

So, you can create  a similar metarig and check which rig type assignement is missing.

[image]

Comment: Is that a custom property? I can't find the menus Rigtype, proxy picker, and wiggle bone under any of my tabs.  I'm using the latest version of blender.

Comment: Wiggle bone is an addon. Rigtype appears only in pose mode, under the bone tab, and it's part of standard Rigify addon, which is enabled by default.